# #1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have a problem with mysql table while try to insert values in database.

I followed this tutorial

http://sqllessons.com/categories.html

and created table like the table from tutorial

**table code**

```
create table categories
( id       integer     not null  primary key 
, name     varchar(37) not null
, parentid integer     null
, foreign key parentid_fk (parentid) 
      references categories (id)
);
```

**error** 
    SQL query: Edit Edit

```
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`categories` (
`id` ,
`name` ,
`parentid`
)
VALUES (
'', 'groceries', NULL
), (
'', 'snacks', NULL
)

MySQL said: Documentation
#1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Help me to solve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declare the value to be auto incrementing and don't insert it.  So:

```
create table categories (
    id       integer     not null  auto_increment primary key,
    name     varchar(37) not null,
    parentid integer     null,
    foreign key parentid_fk (parentid) references categories (id)
);
```

And then:

```
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`categories` (`name`, `parentid`)
    VALUES ('groceries', NULL),
           ('snacks', NULL);
```

Comment: I've commented everyone else's answer so I feel a little bad to not comment yours as well: This answer hits the nail on the head `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert an empty value (0) twice to field, that you said is PRIMARY KEY. Primary key from definition has no duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the primary key as **AUTO_INCREMENT** and no need to insert value for 'id' in the query

Comment: this does not in itself solve the issue [edited answer fixes this issue]

Answer (score 0):

Every Primary Key needs to be unique.
You inserted 2 rows with the Primary key '0'.
Instead of ' ' you should insert an ID.

Edit: Sry my bad, ID not Index.

Comment: insert an index? can you explain what you're talking about here?